# How to configure Google Eearth to show latest imagery?

Tags: google-earth

Each time I use Google Earth and I want to see for instance New York City the program shows images from 2011, but those aren't the latest images because I can click the Historical Images Button to select a later date like 2012.

How do I make Google Earth to show me always the latest images?

Answer (score 1):

Google Earth will default to the highest resolution imagery that is available. If that image happens to be older than the new imagery then you will see that first every time.

You can manually choose to view new imagery by using the Historical Images slider, but are unable to change the default behaviour.

See the Google Earth help page for further information: [Blurry or outdated imagery](https://support.google.com/earth/answer/21417?hl=en)